# Copy to a new directory and Remove files from common directories

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which contains keys and values as below :

defaultdict(, {'A': ['hello.c', 'Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/diff.c', 'Aa/hello2.h'], 'C': ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/sample.h'], 'B': ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/hello2.h']})

From the above dictionary I extracted the common files present in more than one key:

Aa/hello1.c set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
Aa/hello2.h set(['A', 'B'])

These files are stored in a list along with their paths as mentioned above:
['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/hello2.h']

**Now I have created a directory using subprocess and I wanted to 'copy' the common files obtained from those directories to newly created directory and remove the files from actual paths after copying into new directory.**

I'm new to python, could anyone help me out solving the problem as how to traverse into a list when we have files along with common paths and copy from the absolute path and remove from respective paths.

Thanks in advance!!

```
import os
from itertools import chain
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
import pdb
import re
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import shlex
d1 = defaultdict(list)
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        var1 = os.path.join(path, name)
        fileName = var1.split('/')[-1]
        if '.py' in var1: continue
#       pdb.set_trace()
        matchobj=re.match('\.\/([a-zA-z\-])\/(.*)',var1,re.M|re.I)
        if matchobj:
                platform = matchobj.group(1)
                without_platform = matchobj.group(2)
                d1[platform].append(without_platform)
        else:
                print ('not matching')
print(d1)
rev_dict = {}
for key, value in d1.items():
    for i in value:
        rev_dict.setdefault(i, set()).add(key)

for i,j in rev_dict.items():
    if len(j) > 1:
        print ('{} {}'.format(i,j))
var3 = value
print(var3)
var2 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"common_files/")
cmd_exe = subprocess.Popen("mkdir sample", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
cmd_out, cmd_err = cmd_exe.communicate()
```

Comment: Welcome to Python and SO - it's OK to be new, we've all been there. But SO is not here to write your code for you. Please try to solve the problem yourself and if you have a solution that you think should work, but have some issues you can't resolve, share here and ask for help.

Comment: can you show what print(d1) gives you

Comment: print(d1) - defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['hello.c', 'Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/diff.c', 'Aa/hello2.h'], 'C': ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/sample.h'], 'B': ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/hello2.h']})

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os` module.

```
import os

# make a directory
os.mkdir(path)

# removes files/dirs
os.remove(path)

# to move to destination instead of copy and then delete
os.rename(source, destination)
```

You could also use the `shutil` module, described [here](https://datatofish.com/copy-file-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

From what I understand, you can do this:

```
.
.
import shutil

.
.
.
path_list = []
for i,j in rev_dict.items():
    if len(j) > 1:
        for each in j:
            fullpath = each+"/"+i
            path_list.append(fullpath)
print(path_list)

# path_list should now contain the full path
. . .

destination = # new destination path

for source in path_list:
    dest = shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Try it out.

`print(path_list)` gave me this:

```
['A/Aa/hello1.c',
 'B/Aa/hello1.c',
 'C/Aa/hello1.c',
 'A/Aa/hello2.h',
 'B/Aa/hello2.h']
```

Comment: The code provided by you isn't working as the path in the list is not the actual path where file is present. It is just a common path after parent directory among different keys mentioned in dictionary. The actual path would be A/Aa/hello1.c

Comment: So it could be A/Aa/hello1.c or B/Aa/hello1.c based on the default dict key. In that case there are a few ways. If possible save the complete path in the list. Or if possible save list of dict like this:  [ {"root": "A", "path": "Aa/hello1.c"}, ...]. Is any of this possible?

Comment: Thank you!! Currently I'm able to receive defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['hello.c', 'Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/diff.c', 'Aa/hello2.h'], 'C': ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/sample.h'], 'B': ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/hello2.h']})
Aa/hello1.c set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
Aa/hello2.h set(['A', 'B'])
['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/hello2.h']

Comment: Sry can't share my mail-id on a public forum. But you can upload the code here, just change the variable names.

Comment: You can try this code by creating a sample folder structure and place common files(samples)

Comment: print(d1) - defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['hello.c', 'Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/diff.c', 'Aa/hello2.h'], 'C': ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/sample.h'], 'B': ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/hello2.h']})

Comment: Thank you, I'm receiving the list as follows from you code: ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/hello2.h', 'A/Aa/hello1.c', 'C/Aa/hello1.c', 'B/Aa/hello1.c', 'A/Aa/hello2.h', 'B/Aa/hello2.h'] , the common list is also is visible.

Comment: so next is to copy the files from that path to a common directory, can we do this using subprocess ?

Comment: I'm receiving in the path_list as mentioned by you, but  ['Aa/hello1.c', 'Aa/hello2.h', - these two should not come in the list only  [ 'A/Aa/hello1.c', 'C/Aa/hello1.c', 'B/Aa/hello1.c', 'A/Aa/hello2.h', 'B/Aa/hello2.h'] this should come but i'm receiving both in the list

Comment: Sry I'm not familiar with `subprocess`. Not sure why you are getting ['Aa/hello1.c' in the list. Try debugging it, I can't recreate the problem, so it is most likely some bug in your code.